# Configure fonts/colors in Office365's Outlook web app

Tags: microsoft-outlook, fonts, office365

My team was recently migrated to Office 365.  The Windows client works fine however the web version is giving me fits.  In the Office 365 Outlook web view, unread messages blend in with read messages in the list.   In the old web Outlook, unread messages clearly appeared bold.

In 365's web client, the only display config I see controls where the reading pane sits, but no way to set fonts/colors.

Is there some other way to reconfigure how web Outlook looks under Office 365?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, short of being able to add a custom theme to the server - although I'm not sure on how much control that will give you over the look of the web client - you could always look into a browser add-on like 'stylish' to theme the site.

I was able to easily style both my outlook.com and my work outlook web client using it with some simple css styles. (I'm not in anyway affiliated with stylish)

The font is terrible, but you get the idea.

[image]

Comment: That is the Windows client.  I already knew how to configure it.   What I am asking about is the Office 365 Outlook web client.   [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/pi1J27s)   (updated my question to clarify)